# C# WPF - How to get textbox from user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control and a viewmodel for the custom control and they are separate from the mainwindow XAML and the mainwindow viewmodel. In the user control XAML file I have a text box, how do i get it's properties and basically manipulate it in  code in my viewmodel?

I tried with just accessing the textbox's name like that:

```
EditorBox.Text = "Test text";
```

But it doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

That is a fundamental part of that pattern to keep things separated from each other.

To achieve what you want you have to create a property in your `ViewModel` and bind to it in your `View`

Like that

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    private string _text;
    public string Text
        {
            get => _text;
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: But how do i access the textbox by it's name?

More importantly, how do i get dynamically whats being written in the textbox?

Comment: @KrustoStoianov You are unable to access the `TextBox` direct. That's why you need `Binding`, when you set `Text` in your `ViewModel` your `Text Box` will automatically updated and vice versa. Use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and your `Text` property in `ViewModel` will be instant updated when `TextBox.Text` changes. Or what's your goal?